# Modify a REGEX for email subject to add a capture group

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression for filtering a subject line of an email and it strips out the RE/Fwd items very well to just leave the subject itself. Right now this is just matching the RE/FWD parts and while that is useful if i could use it as a find and replace, i need the exact opposite and to add a capture group to capture the subject without the RE/FWD so i can use it elsewhere.

`/([\[\( ] *)?(RE|FWD?) *([-:;)\]][ :;\])-]*|$)|\]+ *$/gims`

and the examples:

```
Fwd : Re : Re: Many
Re : Re: Many
Re  : : Re: Many
Re:: Many
Re; Many
: noah - should not match anything
RE--
RE: : Presidential Ballots for Florida
[RE: (no subject)]
Request - should not match anything
this is the subject (fwd)
 Re: [Fwd: ] Blonde Joke
Re: [Fwd: [Fwd: FW: Policy]]
Re: Fwd: [Fwd: FW: "Drink Plenty of Water"]
FW: FW: (fwd) FW:  Warning from XYZ...
FW: (Fwd) (Fwd) 
Fwd: [Fwd: [Fwd: Big, Bad Surf Moving]]
FW: [Fwd: Fw: drawing by a school age child in PA (fwd)]
Re: Fwd
```

The expected output would be a capture group that i could reference as $1, $2, etc that would contain the subject lines like so:

```
Many
Many
Many
Many
Many
: noah - should not match anything

Presidential Ballots for Florida
(no subject)
Request - should not match anything
this is the subject
Blonde Joke
Policy
"Drink Plenty of Water"
Warning from XYZ...

Big, Bad Surf Moving
drawing by a school age child in PA
```

Comment: Created a version of it here for testing: https://regexr.com/542ru

Answer (score 0):

Add a group to the end of your current regex to capture the subject:

```
([\[\( ] *)?(RE|FWD?) *([-:;)\]][ :;\])-]*|$)|\]+ (.*)
```

Then use group from the match, usually `"$1"` or `"\1"` depending on your language/tool.

Comment: I tried that here: https://regexr.com/542ru but doesn't seem to work group 1 contains part of the RE/FWD

Answer (score 0):

For the example data, you you could match all the variants at the start of the string that you don't want, and capture in group 1 what you want to keep

```
(?:[^\S\r\n]*+[\[(]?(?:re|fwd?)(?!\w)[^\S\r\n]*[:;-]*(?:[^\S\r\n]+[:;-]+)*[^\S\r\n]*[\])]?)+|(\S.*?)(?:\]+|$)
```

Note that this pattern does not take balancing brackets or parenthesis into account.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GYdmHw/1)